# Firebase TestLab XCTest Succeed, but no screenshoots

Tags: ios, firebase, xctest, xcuitest, uitest

I run a XCTest (UI Test) via Firebase TestLab, it's succeed。But no screenshoot

In the case, I make a attachment via "XCTAttachment"

```objectivec
- (void)testHomeButton {
    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    [app launch];
    
    // click button2
    XCUIElement *button2 = app.buttons[@"button2"];
    [button2 tap];
    
    // get button2 screenshoot
    XCTAttachment *attachment1 = [XCTAttachment attachmentWithScreenshot:XCUIScreen.mainScreen.screenshot];
    attachment1.name = @"button2 Screen";
    attachment1.lifetime = XCTAttachmentLifetimeKeepAlways;
    [self addAttachment:attachment1];
    
    // click button3
    XCUIElement *button3 = app.buttons[@"button3"];
    [button3 tap];
    
    // get button3 screenshoot
    XCTAttachment *attachment2 = [XCTAttachment attachmentWithScreenshot:XCUIScreen.mainScreen.screenshot];
    attachment2.name = @"button3 Screen";
    attachment2.lifetime = XCTAttachmentLifetimeKeepAlways;
    [self addAttachment:attachment2];
    
    // click testview
    XCUIElement *testview = [app.otherElements.element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeAny][@"testvc_view"];
    [testview tap];
}
```

I have got screenshoot successfully via xcode test (command + U)
[xcode test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMDif.png)

However the test result of firebase has no screenshoot attachments, only contains logs and videos

What should I do to get the screenshot？

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've no experience with Firebase TestLab for XCTest but I would assume they provide their own reporting. If you can get an *.xcresult file from Firebase you will be able to see it the same way as in Xcode

Comment: Yes, their reporting contains an *.xcresult file, but How can I get  the screenshot from *.xcresult file

Comment: If you can download that *.xcresult file you can open it in Xcode and will look exactly as in your screenshot. If for some reason you don't see screenshots in that *.xcresult file I would advise you to:
1. Click Edit scheme
2. Open Test configuration
3. Tap on Options
4. Validate that "Capture screenshots automatically" is checked
5. If it is checked - validate "Delete when each tests succeeds" is unchecked.
If you have that last option enabled for your scheme you will see screenshots only for failing tests.